# F# What is this [<something>]?

Tags: f#, operator-keyword, .net-attributes

I have come across something like this:

```
[<Activity (Label = "setView", MainLauncher = true)>]
```

several times and i have been wondering what is `[<something>]` and what does it do? I would gladly read up on it but i can't since i have no clue what it is called or what it does?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/attributes

Comment: Those are attributes, and depending on what libraries you use you will most often come across [<EntryPoint>] for the main function, [<STAThread>] if you do GUI programming, and maybe [<CLIMutable>] if you expose your records to C#/.NET.

Comment: Also [<Flags>] for combinable enums.

Comment: @s952163 and idjarn: you added your answer as a comment. Because of this the question looks unanswered and the person who asked the question can't mark it as being the answer to their question. You'll loose out on reputation points too.

Comment: @norbertB : Feel free. :-] I hesitate because it's an obvious duplicate, but I can't find a good candidate for duplicate-of nomination offhand.